# Centering buttons and text in a GridPane (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, centering

I have a simple display that has a title at the very top, a list in the middle, and then three buttons at the bottom. I want the title at the top and the buttons at the bottom to be horizontally centered.

Here is the code that I've been trying to use:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane
    xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.40"
    xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
    fx:controller="controllers.SongLibraryController"
>
    <Label
        text="Todo List"
        GridPane.columnSpan="3"
        GridPane.rowIndex="0"
        GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
    />
    <ListView
        prefWidth="300"
        prefHeight="400"
        fx:id="listView"
        GridPane.columnSpan="3"
        GridPane.rowIndex="1"
    />
    <Button
        fx:id="editItem"
        GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="0"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2"
        text="Edit Item"
    />
    <Button
        fx:id="addItem"
        GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="1"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2"
        text="Add Item"
    />
    <Button
        fx:id="deleteItem"
        GridPane.halignment="CENTER"
        GridPane.columnIndex="2"
        GridPane.rowIndex="2"
        text="Delete Item"
    />
</GridPane>
```

And here is the current output:

[image]

I've tried doing various things like using `alignment="CENTER"` for my GridPane, but nothing seems to be working. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set alignment for your GridPane as `alignment="center"` and all elements will be aligned in center.

**Update**
You can align your buttons in center like this.

```
<HBox GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.columnSpan="3" alignment="CENTER" spacing="25">
    <Button text="b1"/>
    <Button text="b2"/>
    <Button text="b3"/>
</HBox>
```

After this update you also can delete columnSpan attribute from each node.

Comment: I had actually already tried `alignment="CENTER"`, and I've updated my code in my example to show that. It didn't have any impact on the generated output.

Comment: @meh_programmer, review my answer

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thanks so much!

Comment: @meh_programmer np, gl bro ;)

Answer (score 3):

To align elements inside a grid pane programatically, you will have to call static methods from the GridPane class.

To set horizontal alignment, call `GridPane.setHalignment(Node n, HPos p)`. To set vertical alignment, call `GridPane.setValignment(Node n, VPos p)`.

You can read Oracle's own layout guide [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm). If you scroll down until you see the pie chart, they show an example of how to manage layouts in grid panes.

To manage it via FXML, you will have to set a certain property. I can't remember of the top of my head, but I think it is `alignment="center"` in your GridPane node.

Comment: It looks like setting `GridPane.halignment="CENTER"` to the `Label` centered it, thanks! However, it doesn't seem to work for the buttons. I've updated my screenshot. Is there something I can do so that the three buttons are centered horizontally? Also as a side note, for some reason setting `alignment="CENTER"` on my `GridPane` has no effect. Anyways, upvoting your answer since it helped a bit!

Comment: I think you can align the entire GridPane to centered, by adding `<GridPane> alignment="CENTER"</GridPane>`, just like GVArt suggested.